# Can a Vue Boolean prop be true by its presence and false by its absence?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In my Vue component, I have a Boolean prop called "obj", defined like this:

```
obj: { Type:Boolean, default: false}
```

I can set it to `true` like this:

```
<my-component :obj="true"></my-component>
```

However, I'd like to be able to set it to `true` like this:

```
<my-component obj></my-component>
```

I'd like the presence of the prop to mean `true` and its absence to mean `false`. Is there a way to define a prop that works this way in a Vue component?

Comment: That second example should work just as you say, right? Have you tried? I can't check, on mobile atm

Comment: @kingdaro When I simply use the prop name it's value is an empty string in my component.

Comment: Could you show the source for your component? Also, in your props definition, it should be lowercase `type`, not Type. Unless that's a typo

Comment: @kingdaro You're right. The capital T in type was messing it up and not making it a Boolean. Thank you.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

That's the behavior of a Boolean prop in any case. You simply define the prop as:

```js
{
  props: {
    fast: Boolean
  }
  ...
}
```

And it defaults to `false`. When you specify the attribute at all in the following template, it is set to `true`:

```html
<my-foo fast/>  <!-- fast is true -->
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ymlk88kqkz)

Comment: You're right. I had a capital T in "Type" which was messing it up. Thank you.